# How to use as a custom icon component phosphor icon with Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, material-ui, icons, vuetify.js

I am working on a Vuejs Vuetify 2 project.
In this project I am using PhosphorIcons https://github.com/phosphor-icons/phosphor-vue
The only problem I am facing in this icon package; when I want to use as a string name it does not show me the icons.

Because of that i have checked vuetify documentation. It says i can use custom icon font. But I dont know how to achieve this.

For instance i have items and i am using inside a foor loop.

```
    items: [
      {
        text: "dashboardPage.title",
        route: "/dashboard",
        icon: "ph-archieve-tray",
      },
      {
        text: "employeePage.title",
        route: "/employees",
        icon: "ph-archieve-tray",
      },
      {
        text: "extractionRequestPage.title",
        route: "/extraction-requests",
        icon: "mdi-inbox-arrow-down-outline",
      },
      {
        text: "extractionOngoingPage.sidebarTitle",
        route: "/extractions-ongoing",
        icon: "ph-archive-tray",
      },
      {
        text: "activeTVAsPage.sideBarTitle",
        route: "/active-tvas",
        icon: "mdi-poll",
      },
      {
        text: "issues&warningsPage.title",
        route: "",
        icon: "mdi-alert-outline",
      },
      {
        text: "adminPanelPage.title",
        route: "",
        icon: "mdi-cog-outline",
      },
    ],
```

and as i said this is the foor loop.

```
      <v-list-item-group v-model="selected" active-class="active-item">
        <v-list-item
          v-for="item in items"
          :key="item.text"
          router
          :to="item.route"
        >
          <v-list-item-icon>
            <!-- <component :is="item.icon" /> -->
            <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
          </v-list-item-icon>

          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title size="12">{{
              $tc(item.text, 0)
            }}</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
```

ONLY THE MATERIAL ICONS SHOW ME THE icons but ph-archive-tray is not working. Please help me. Thanks

I have tried to add custom icon component but does not work

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain an idea about what you could do about this:

1. Your approach using inbuilt `Component` is right. `phosphor-icon` provides icons as SVG components, so for dynamic loading, `Component` is the right way.
2. You should import every icon you need and set in the `icon` prop from the array to achieve first statement. A `icon: () => import(PhHorse)` should be ok (importing here as an async component, see [this](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/async.html#basic-usage)).
3. For props into that component, I suggest convert `icon` prop to a non-primitive one like a object.

```json
icon: {
  component: () => import(PhHorse),
  props: {
    size: "32"
    color: "hotpink"
    weight: "fill"
  }
}
```

With this, you should accessing any icon component in your template:

```html
  <component 
     :is="item.icon.component" 
     :size="item.icon.props.size" 
     :color="item.icon.props.color" 
     :weight="item.icon.prop.weight
  />
```

4. If you are thinking using mdi and phosphor icons, you might wrap that code portion into a `template` with a function to get if `icon` has a `props` prop, so you can know when load a `v-list-item-icon` or `component`.